# Jquery onClick toggleClass: only one div at a time

Tags: jquery

I have a menu which I target using the jquery function below. Problem is when home is clicked and highlighted and you want to jump to products from there both are active + both block-1 and block-2 show.

What I am trying to do is that when the user clicked on A and from there decides to switch to B then A is inactive and so on. The only class that stays constant meanwhile one of the menu items is active is "content-removed".

What am I missing?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".home").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("item-active");
        $(".block-1").toggleClass("display");
        $(".b1").toggleClass("visibility");
        $(".content").toggleClass("content-removed");
    });
    $(".products").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("item-active");
        $(".block-2").toggleClass("display");
        $(".b2").toggleClass("visibility");
        $(".content").toggleClass("content-removed");
    });
});
```

Here the HTML

```
  <div class="block-1">
  <div class="b1"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
    <div class="b1"><a href="#">About</a></div>
  </div>

    <div class="block-2">
  <div class="b2"><a href="#">Overview</a></div>
    <div class="b2"><a href="#">Health</a></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your code?

Comment: And post relevant HTML in question...

Comment: @BojanPetkovski I will try now

Comment: From what you explained what you want. Other than using `toggleClass`, hide all other items when you show one.